# How to build week data in calendar for my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

I am trying to build a calendar modal for my app by using Angular. I have a model like this

I have no problem building the year month but not sure how to setup the week that has other day. For example, first week of Oct has 28,29,30 in the first week.

```
//code to build day
var month = 9; // hardcoded for demo.
var monthA = [];
for (var m = 0; m <= 3; m ++) {
    var weeks = [];
    totalDay = new Date(year, month + m + 1, 0).getDate()             
    //build days
    for (var i = 0; i <= totalDay; i++) {
         //setting up weeks
         if (i % 7 == 0) {
              weeks.push([]);
         }
         weeks[weeks.length-1].push(i);
     }

     var monthObj = {
         month : (month + m),
         weeks:weeks
     }

     monthA.push(monthObj);
}
```

The above code will produce

```
   monthA:
            [
                {
                    month: '10',
                    weeks: [
                            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                            [8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
                            [15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
                            [21,22,23,24,25,26,27],
                            [28,29,30,31]
                          ]
                },
                {
                    month: 'Nov',
                    weeks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ...
                }...
            ]
        }
```

I was hoping to get

```
month:
        [
            {
                month: '10',
                weeks: [
                        [28, 29, 30, 1,2,3,4], //I haven o problem building the week from 1 to 4
                        [5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                        [12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
                        [19,20,21,22,23,24,25],
                        [26,27,28,29,30,31,1]
                      ]
            },
            {
                month: '11',
                weeks: [26,27,28,29,30,31,1] ...
            }
        ]
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function I just made should do what you want:

```js
function getWeeksinMonth(year, month){ //month 1-12 based
      var weeks = [];
        lastDayinMonth = new Date(year, month, 0)  // get last day in month
        firstDayinMonth = new Date(year, month-1, 1)  //get first day in month
        start =  new Date(firstDayinMonth.getTime()); //copy firstDay
        start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay() ); // set date to previous sunday
        end=new Date(lastDayinMonth.getTime()); //copy lastDay
        end.setDate(end.getDate() - end.getDay() ); // set date to previous sunday
        if(end < lastDayinMonth){ // if previous sunday was not the lastDay itself, we want to add another week
            end.setDate(end.getDate() + 7);
        }    
        var counter=0;
        var week=[]
        for(;start<=end;start.setDate(start.getDate()+1)){ // traverse days
            if(counter % 7==0 && counter != 0){ // every 7 days add a week
                var copy=week.slice(0);
                weeks.push(copy)
                week=[];
            }
            week.push(start.getDate())
            counter++
        } 
        return weeks;
    }
    
    var weeks = getWeeksinMonth(2014,10);
    for(var i=0;i<weeks.length;i++){
        document.body.innerHTML+=weeks[i].toString() + '<br/>';
    }
```